# How do we interpret multiple regression linear regression that have categorical variable?

Tags: multiple-regression, interpretation

**Formula**

```
log(sale) = price+ads_rating_tv+ads_rating_banner+Jan+Feb+Mar+May+Jun+Jul+Aug+Sep+Oct+Nov+Dec+time+North+South+West+East+time
```

**Variable**

sales = unit sales

price = price of product

ads_rating_tv= rating from ads on tv

ads_rating_banner= rating from ads on banner

month (categorical) = Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec

time (categorical) = 1,2,3...36

region = Capital, North, South, West, East

I am having hard time to interpret this linear regression formula, these are some questions that I am with the formula:

1. What is the sales contribution from ads_rating_tv and ads_rating_banner variable? (How can I
2. How do we interpret the dummy vairables that aren't in the formula? (Apr and Capital)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "does being in a certain month helps to sell more than average"

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Thank you for your question. Yes, I did plot the graph and saw that on average, some months (Jun and Dec) mean sales is visibilty higher than others.

Comment: That's the interpretations of the categorical coefficients